# Some parts of the body content disappear under the header

Tags: html, css

Some parts of the body content disappear under the header. And when zoom in and out, body view is changing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="elan.css" />

    <title>site</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="img/img1.png" alt="" /></a>
      <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">Əsas səhifə</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">haqqında</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Olimpiadalar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Elanlar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Qalereya </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bizimlə əlaqə</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="right">
        <div class="registration regtop">
          <a href="#" class="button">Qeydiyyat</a>
        </div>
        <div class="language-dropdown">
          <select id="language-selector">
            <option value="en">AZ</option>
            <option value="es">EN</option>
            <option value="fr">RU</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section cl>
      <h1>CONTACT ASSOCIATION</h1>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Screenshoot

I tried different ways. But i cannot solve this issue

Comment: cannot reproduce the issue you're describing. My educated guess would be, that you used `position: fixed` for the header instead of `position: sticky`